# I can't find my other HDD

Tags: hard-drive

New Ubuntu user here... I have Ubuntu on my 250GB SSD and I have another 500GB on my laptop that Ubuntu can't find. I'm not sure where or how to start finding it.

Comment: Typing `lsblk` in a terminal window should return a list of all the partitions on your system, including ones that are not mounted.

Answer (score 5):

You might need to edit your /etc/fstab to mount your extra drive. Here's how you can check.

Type `lsblk` into a terminal like Organic Marble suggested. Devices named like `sda`, `sdb`, and `sdc` are going to be distinct drives, while `sda1`, `sda2`, etc are partitions of that drive.

If your drive isn't showing up in `lsblk`, then someone more experienced than I will need to answer your question. I'd guess it means that your drive isn't connected properly, but I don't know for sure.

However, if you do see a drive that's showing up in `lsblk`, but doesn't have a  MOUNTPOINT, then we can likely assume that it's your drive, and we can follow a few simple steps to get it set up. Let's assume that your device is `sdb`.

First, figure out which partition of your 500gb drive you want to mount. If you have multiple partitions, then you'll need to do this for each partition. Let's assume you want `sdb1`.

Next, you need to figure out where you want to mount the partition to. I usually end up mounting all of my drives in the `/media` directory, with a subdirectory for the partition. for example, my local network share is mounted in `/media/fileshare`. Either way, decide where you want to mount this partition, and create a folder for it, like this: `sudo mkdir -p /path/to/mount/directory`.

Next you need to figure out the filesystem type. Type `sudo parted -l` to get a list of all drives connected to the computer. Find the drive in the list that matches your drive. The partitions will be listed starting at 1; note the column for 'file system'. Let's assume yours is `ext4`.

Now, open your `/etc/fstab` file with root permissions using your favorite text editor. Nano is pretty easy to use: `sudo nano /etc/fstab`. The `fstab` file contains information about all the drives that get mounted to your computer and tells the OS how and where to mount them. You should see a couple lines in there which correlate to your main drive as well as your swap space. You want to add a new line sort of like this one, but with whatever the values you came up with are:

```
# partition   mount location  filesystem  options   dump   pass
/dev/sdb1    /media/fileshare    ext4    defaults,     0    2
```

Where the `defaults` refers to all of the default options found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab). I'm no expert on `fstab` options, but someone else might be able to help you more here.

Now, save and quit whatever text editor you used, and run the command `sudo mount -a`; this re-mounts all partitions found in `fstab`. Assuming you did everything right, your partition should be mounted, and you should be able to access your files from whatever mount point you specified in the `fstab` file.

Comment: Hey here's a screen shot of my terminal [https://i.imgur.com/YTboM8t.png]. I think "sdb" is the 500 gb hardrive with "core" (idk what that is). Oh on "loop1" I have the Atom that I can't run when I click the icon but runs when I 'sudo atom' in the terminal.

Comment: Looks like `sdb1` is the partition you want to mount. For `sudo parted`, you want to use `-l` (lowercase L), not `-1` (the numeral one).

Comment: @NotThatGood, did you get this working?